# UWP Application with video playback

Tags: c#, xaml, video, uwp, playback

How can I get the time of video playback in UWP C# Application?

I'm using Media Element and I have video playback in my app after I choose it from the file. I can pause it and start it again, but I don't know how can I get the real time of this video, when it's playing.

Comment: `MediaElement.Position` will allow you to get or set the playback position. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.position

Answer (score 0):

For retrieve current position of duration look at the `MediaElement.Position` property.

> The amount of time since the beginning of the media. The default is a TimeSpan with value 0:0:0

If you want to know the playback duration you can use `MediaElement.NaturalDuration` property:

> The natural duration of the media. The default value is a Duration structure that evaluates as Automatic, which is the value held if you query this property before MediaOpened.

Comment: `Binding Path=Position.TotalSeconds` perfectly works

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind on Position property of MediaLement like this:

```
    <MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position, ElementName=MediaElement1}"/>
```

Comment: Yes, it's almost working.
I'm using:

`Binding Path=Position.TotalSeconds`

Thanks for help!